# Find elements on Python Selenium - one element short

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium, screen-scraping

I am seeing a very odd bug on the function "find_elements_by_css_selector" on selenium. 
Applying a selector that should return 10 elements it returns 9 instead, consistently on all different page examples I tried. 
Same selector I tested with javascript "querySelectorAll" and indeed returned 10, so the css selector works fine.

Anyone had this "one element short" bug too?

Comment: what element? What selector? Show it and then we can check why it doesn't get it. For Selenium it can be different element.

Comment: @supputuri you're wrong

Comment: can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @supputuri `len()` will still be 10 but the final index will be 9 (because it starts at 0)

Comment: Hi, The guidance related to this goes as follows: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:  [mcve]_.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the test:

```
css = 'a[href]' # your css goes here
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(css)
print(len(elements))

elements = driver.execute_script("""
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(arguments[0])]
""", css)
print(len(elements))
```

I'd be interested to hear if the numbers are really different. If so, you found a bug.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did and got different numbers.

Comment: Cool, you should post an issue on their github page in that case. And maybe use the second way from now on.